# Return a mock http response instead of server call in angular4

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, angular5

I have a function `myFunc()` which i subscribe to.

If it is called with X then i want it to be a normal HTTP response from the Server.

If it is called without X, i want it to return a 'fake' http response with an empty array as a result.

How can i do this? I have tried returning an empty observable, but the subscribe never triggers.

```
myFunc(x) {
  if (x) {
    return this.http.get('myURL');
  } else {
    return Observable.from<Response>([])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `Observable.from<Response>([])` with `Observable.of<Response>([])`.

```
return Observable.of<Response>([])
```

This is because `Observable.from` iterates the input array and emits all its items. Since the array is empty it won't emit anything. `Observable.of` just takes what you pass as a parameter and sends it as `next` followed by the `complete` notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can return something like this and it will trigger your subscription:

```
return Observable.of<any>({ isSuccess: false });
```

Here you can pass any object. I just created simple object `{ isSuccess: false }`

Answer (score 0):

Observable.empty won't trigger the onNext function of the subscription, but will trigger the onComplete. You could put some of this logic there. Alternatively, you could use

```
return Observable.just(null);
```

to return an Observable with null data